# Using the iOS Keyboard with Phonegap without a Form/Input Field?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, ipad

Is there a way to access the iOS (iPhone / iPad) keyboard for text / numeric input without attaching it to a form/input when using Phonegap / jQuery for development? I would like to have the keyboard pop-up on an anchor click and once the 'return' key is pressed, take the content and place it in a div via JS.

I checked the APIs and the stack but haven't found anything that would work; is it even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After quite a bit of research and testing it appears the only way to access the iOS keyboard / keypad using Phonegap is to use inputs with HTML5 Input Type ('email', 'tel' etc.) Here's a great resource: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/768.cfm

For non-input fields the best solution is to use a JS keypad and write custom handlers for the inputs. I found this great jQuery plugin from Keith Wood that does the trick: http://keith-wood.name/keypad.html

I hope this helps some one!